# Add New Column in Nested SELECT with DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, select, datediff

Admitted SQL newbie here but I'm working on a query where the request just got more complicated. Long short of it is that I have a table with a few columns. One of which is a date column.

I'm writing a query to return a set of columns along with adding a new column based on the date range (<=90 Days, 91-180, 180+). This is what I have so far. It works for the first 90 but I'm having a hard timing nesting the other select commands to get the other data sets.

```
Select Key, Name, 'C90' as Code
From LD_List
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,[LAST_PURCHASE_DATE],GETDATE()) <= 90
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: What SQL are you using? SQL server? MYSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using TSQL, SQL Server or MYSQL you may use, `CASE WHEN` : Key is a **resreved keyword**. So use squre brackets. In my sample I have used key as id.

- [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f35d/1)

Query: SQL Server version:

```
Select id, Name, 
case when DATEDIFF(DAY,[LAST_PURCHASE_DATE],GETDATE()) <= 90 
Then 'C90' 
when (DATEDIFF(DAY,[LAST_PURCHASE_DATE],GETDATE()) >= 91 
and DATEDIFF(DAY,[LAST_PURCHASE_DATE],GETDATE()) <= 180) 
then 'C180' 
else 'C181' 
end AS Code
From LD_List
```

Results:

```
ID  NAME    CODE
1   john    C181
2   tim     C181
3   jack    C181
4   kate    C181
5   jim     C181
6   ron     C180
7   henry   C180
8   liza    C90
```

---

### EXTRA :)

Now if you need a pivot like the following: Check this * [SQLFIDDLE Demonstration out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f35d/14)

Results:

```
CODE    PURCHASERS
C180    ron,henry
C181    john,tim,jack,kate,jim
C90     liza
```

Comment: This did the trick! I changed some of the Column names to mask the project a little bit more but I appreciate the help! Thanks again!

Comment: @user1919851 glad you got it worked. Then vote up so system gets updated that your query is solved. And if you want to slice the results to show a pivot like MYSQL `group_concat` you can give it a try with `XML PATH`, `Stuff` functions.. :) let us know if you got doubts.

Comment: I need 15 rep to upvote. Odd I can't even upvote my own question.

Comment: @user1919851 but you can click on the white tick which will turn into green. That can be done without any extra rep. And if you want to earn reps initially you may 1. post good questions 2. post good answers. **3.edit others' questions (any typos, code snippet formatting, html formatting, propper retagging, title amendments)** **4. edit wiki tags**

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Key, Name,
   CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,[LAST_PURCHASE_DATE],GETDATE()) <= 90 THEN 'C90'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,[LAST_PURCHASE_DATE],GETDATE()) >= 91 AND DATEDIFF(DAY,[LAST_PURCHASE_DATE],GETDATE()) <= 180 THEN 'C180'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,[LAST_PURCHASE_DATE],GETDATE()) >= 181 THEN 'C181'
   END AS Code
```